# Wordpress - Save values to array upon form submit in admin option page

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, submit

I have almost done a successful first time plugin, but unfortunately I cannot submit my updated values to the array I've created upon my register_activation_hook.

I need some insights in how Wordpress can handle all the dirty work - or will a $_POST be a better way to do it?

Below you'll see my admin.php which handles all admin related stuff.

```
<?php 

// Meaning of abbreviations:
// clsc = Custom login shortcode

// Runs when plugin is activated
register_activation_hook( PLUGIN_MAIN_FILE, 'clsc_install');
// Create new database fields
function clsc_install() {
    $clsc_options = array(

        'Login_link'        => '/log-in/',
        'Login_string'      => __('Log in', 'clsc'),
        'Login_class'       => '', // Default is empty to inherit theme styles
        'Logout_link'       => wp_logout_url( home_url()),
        'Logout_string'     => __('Log out', 'clsc'),
        'Logout_class'      => '', // Default is empty to inherit theme styles
        'Account_link'      => '/my-account/',
        'Account_string'    => __('My Account', 'clsc'),
        'Account_class'     => '' // Default is empty to inherit theme styles

    );
    add_option('clsc_options_array', $clsc_options, '', 'yes');
}


// Create admin option page
function add_clsc_option_page() {
    add_options_page(
        'Custom Login',             // The text to be displayed in the title tag
        'Custom Login',             // The text to be used for the menu
        'administrator',            // The capability required to display this menu
        'custom-login-shortcodes',  // The unique slug name to refer to this menu
        'clsc_html_page');          // The function to output the page content
}
/* Call the html code */
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_clsc_option_page');

// Enqueue admin styles and scripts
function clsc_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $wpdb;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->id != 'settings_page_custom-login-shortcodes' ) {
        return; // exit if incorrect screen id
    } 

        wp_enqueue_style( 'brokenfruit-shortcodes-styles', plugins_url( 'admin/css/admin_styles.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('admin/css/bootstrap.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap_hack', plugins_url('admin/scripts/bootstrap-hack.js', dirname(__FILE__) ) );

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'clsc_enqueue_scripts' );

// Build admin interface
function clsc_html_page(){

    $options = get_option('clsc_options_array');

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
        <div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1><?php _e('Custom Login Shortcode','clsc'); ?></h1>
                    <p><?php _e('To use for shortcode:','clsc'); ?><br/><span class="shortcode-preview">[custom_login]</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="login-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /log-in/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: Log in', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: login_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer" id="logout-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /log-out/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: Log out', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: logout_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer" id="account-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /my-account/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: My Account', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input placeholder="<?php _e('Example: account_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="clsc_options_array" />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary top-buffer" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Feedback for alternative approaches are more than welcome!

I thank you all in advance and have a great day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have update function `clsc_html_page()` and added action `'admin_init'` to save register your setting fields.

```
    /** 
Plugin Name: clsc
Plugin URI: http://google.com/
Description: this is description
Version: 1.0
Author: authourname
Author URI: http://authoururri.com/
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: text domain
*/

// Runs when plugin is activated
register_activation_hook( PLUGIN_MAIN_FILE, 'clsc_install');
// Create new database fields
function clsc_install() {
    $clsc_options = array(

        'Login_link'        => '/log-in/',
        'Login_string'      => __('Log in', 'clsc'),
        'Login_class'       => '', // Default is empty to inherit theme styles
        'Logout_link'       => wp_logout_url( home_url()),
        'Logout_string'     => __('Log out', 'clsc'),
        'Logout_class'      => '', // Default is empty to inherit theme styles
        'Account_link'      => '/my-account/',
        'Account_string'    => __('My Account', 'clsc'),
        'Account_class'     => '' // Default is empty to inherit theme styles

    );
    add_option('clsc_options_array', $clsc_options, '', 'yes');
}

add_action('admin_init','admin_init_register_setting');
function admin_init_register_setting()
{    
    // register your plugins settings    
    /*register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Account_class');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Account_string');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Account_link');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Logout_class');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Logout_string');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Logout_link');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Login_class');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Login_string');  
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'Login_link');  */
    register_setting('wp_plugin_template-group', 'clsc_options_array');

}  

// Create admin option page
function add_clsc_option_page() {
    add_options_page(
        'Custom Login',             // The text to be displayed in the title tag
        'Custom Login',             // The text to be used for the menu
        'administrator',            // The capability required to display this menu
        'custom-login-shortcodes',  // The unique slug name to refer to this menu
        'clsc_html_page');          // The function to output the page content
}
/* Call the html code */
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_clsc_option_page');

// Enqueue admin styles and scripts
function clsc_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $wpdb;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen->id != 'settings_page_custom-login-shortcodes' ) {
        return; // exit if incorrect screen id
    } 

        wp_enqueue_style( 'brokenfruit-shortcodes-styles', plugins_url( 'admin/css/admin_styles.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('admin/css/bootstrap.css', dirname(__FILE__) ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_js_bootstrap_hack', plugins_url('admin/scripts/bootstrap-hack.js', dirname(__FILE__) ) );

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'clsc_enqueue_scripts' );

function clsc_html_page()
{
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
    {
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">        
        <form method="post" action="options.php"> 
            <?php
              $options = get_option('clsc_options_array');     
            @settings_fields('wp_plugin_template-group'); ?>
            <?php @do_settings_fields('wp_plugin_template-group'); ?>          
            <div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1><?php _e('Custom Login Shortcode','clsc'); ?></h1>
                    <p><?php _e('To use for shortcode:','clsc'); ?><br/><span class="shortcode-preview">[custom_login]</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="login-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Login_link]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /log-in/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Login_string]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: Log in', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log in class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Login_class]"  placeholder="<?php _e('Example: login_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Login_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer" id="logout-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Logout_link]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /log-out/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Logout_string]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: Log out', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Log out class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Logout_class]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: logout_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Logout_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row top-buffer" id="account-content">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account link:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Account_link]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: /my-account/', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_link']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account string:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Account_string]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: My Account', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_string']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h5><?php _e('Account class:','clsc'); ?></h5>
                    <input name="clsc_options_array[Account_class]" placeholder="<?php _e('Example: account_style', 'clsc') ?>" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $options['Account_class']; ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
            <?php @submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php


}
```

Comment: This is very nice! It really shows that Wordpress can do the dirty work as I talked about!
I'm curious in the "@" used for settings_fields and do_settings_fields.
Furthermore, why is @settings_fields not enough? - why we need to do the "do_settings_fields" ? :)

Comment: you can remove '@'.just visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002610/character-before-a-function-call for details

Answer (score 1):

**You can go ahead with POST Method as you used a form so upon submission use `update_option` to update your option values.**

Reference URL :

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

How to use `update_option` :

```
function my_option_function() { 
   update_option('option_value','none'); 
} 
add_action('update_option', 'my_option_function'); ?>
```

For more guidance,Take a look at :

[WordPress functions.php: how to apply update_option()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297400/wordpress-functions-php-how-to-apply-update-option)